# Rectangular divs using percentage based width and height calculation not appearing

Tags: html, css

Two rectangular divs using percentage based width and height calculation are not appearing for me.  Here is all the HTML from the body:

```
<div class="brd"></div>
<img src="res/logo-art.png" alt="Logo Artwork" align="middle" width="100%">
<button class="btn btn-default" id="login">Login</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="register">Register</button>
<div class="brd"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.brd {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(50% - 315px);
    background: #606060;
}
```

The height of the page is 854px, so I worked out the height of each div to be 112px.  The height of the png image is 475px.  The inspector shows that the height of each div is 0px.

Answer (score 1):

Even without calculation this wouldn't work. To express the hight in percentage of the screen it is better to use "vh" units (viewport height):

```
.brd {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(50vh - 315px);
    background: #606060;
}
```

http://codepen.io/1GR3/pen/amLKVG

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens to me that percentage based widths and heights on a div element don't work. I used to fix it by giving all my div's parent a css width / height. So, if your `div.brd` is son of `body`, do:

```
html, body {
  width: {some_value};
  height: {some_value};
}
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
.brd {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(50% - 315px);
    background: #606060;
    height: -moz-calc(50% - 315px);
    height: -webkit-calc(50% - 315px);
}

Try this. It works
```