# SVG rect is Responsive with CSS in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive

I figured out two ways to make an element inside an SVG have responsive resizing relative to the SVG's parent or the SVG itself (SVG height is 100% anyway):

- 1. Change the height in CSS using CSS variables

  - **Works in Firefox but not Chrome, and I have no idea why?**
- 2. Change the height in JS by getting the SVG's parent's height

  - Works in Firefox and Chrome, but as much as possible I would like the resizing logic to be all in one place (i.e. CSS only)

This is a simplified version of what I want for ease of readability. In my project I'm trying to build an SVG nav button that looks like a vertical border with an arrow in the center of it, where the arrow stays the same size, but the vertical lines above and below it change with the button height, and the button height is `100vh - 100px` to make room for the header and footer that are `50px` each for now. For this reason I need the viewbox dimensions to be responsive in addition to the SVG's height, so I can't do this part in CSS.

https://codepen.io/Daniel-WR-Hart/pen/PoKPebb

`approach1.html` : JS only handles the viewbox resizing

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Responsive SVG Rect</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:,">
    <style>
        :root {
            --view-box-half: calc(50%);
            --rect-thick: calc(25px);
            --end-gap: calc(50px);
            --longer-side: calc(var(--view-box-half) - var(--end-gap));
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        rect {
            width: var(--rect-thick);
            height: var(--longer-side);
        }

        button {
            width: 50px;
            margin: var(--end-gap) 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: calc(100vh - 100px);
            background-color: blue;

            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
        }
        svg {
            opacity: 0.7;
            transition: opacity 0.4s;
        }
        svg:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script type="module" defer>
        const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
        const parent = svg.parentNode; // a button
        const rect = document.querySelector('rect');
        setResponsiveArrowResizing();

        function setResponsiveArrowResizing() {
            window.addEventListener('load', updateSizes);
            window.addEventListener('resize', updateSizes);
            function updateSizes() {
                updateViewBoxSize();
                updateRectSize();
            }
            function updateViewBoxSize() {
                // (0,0) is in the center of the svg's viewBox
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = parent.offsetWidth / -2;
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = parent.offsetHeight / -2;
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = parent.offsetWidth;
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = parent.offsetHeight;
            }
            function updateRectSize() {
                // Handled in CSS
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 0 0" style="background-color: rgb(150, 40, 40)">
            <rect/>
        </svg>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

`approach2.html`
: Same as `approach1.html` but with these changes, so that JS handles changing the height of the `rect` instead of CSS:

```
        rect {
            width: var(--rect-thick);
            /* height: var(--longer-side); */
        }

            function updateRectSize() {
                rect.style.height = parent.offsetHeight / 2 - 50 + 'px';
            }
```

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819308/rectangular-divs-using-percentage-based-width-and-height-calculation-not-appeari  

Comment: That's a vaguely similar problem that doesn't even use SVGs. I think their problem is that they're assuming that body has a default height of 100vh, when it's actually 0px without content, or content with a height that's % based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case replacing `--view-box-half: calc(50%);` with `--view-box-half: calc((100vh - 100px) / 2);` should do the job (and would be the easiest solution)

Check [your updated working example here](https://codepen.io/Berci/pen/YzxpeXB)

I think the issue with percentage height is related to [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) and [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

> The viewBox attribute defines the position and dimension, in user space, of an SVG viewport.

While the height is updating the viewport stays the same therefore the height of the rect is not updated. [here is an interesting question that might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699098/responsive-svg-viewbox)